# ng-view doesn't showing anything in my angularJS app

Tags: angularjs

I'm new in Angular. I have a simple application for routing pages in angular. I have two pages which I want angular to change the URL pages:

// item1.html:

```
<section>{{name}}</section>
```

// item2.html:

```
<section>{{details}}</section>
```

and this is my HTML home page:

```
<body ng-app="myApp">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
        <div class="container-fluid">
          <div class="navbar-header">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">WebSiteName</a>
          </div>
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="active"><a href="# ">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#/item1">Item 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#/item2">Item 2</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </nav>

      <div class="container" ng-view>
        <h3>Basic Navbar Example</h3>
        <p>A navigation bar is a navigation header that is placed at the top of the page.</p>
      </div>      
</body>
```

// routeApp.js:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', [
 "ngRoute",
 'personController'
]);

myApp.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider){
$routeProvider.
when('/',{
    templateUrl:'partial/item1.html',
    controller:'ListController'
}).when('/item2',{
    templateUrl:'partial/item2.html',
    controller:'DetailsController'
}).otherwise({
    redirect:'/'
});
}]);
```

// routeController.js:

```
var personController = angular.module("personController",[]);

personController.controller("ListController", function($scope){
$scope.name="Ali Qadomy";
});

personController.controller("DetailsController", function($scope){
$scope.details="Angular Developers";
});
```

I've spent more than two days looking at the problem but I can't find it.
any help ?

Comment: What is your angularjs version?

Comment: Also do you have any console warnings or errors?